# Name of Stack Exchange app is too long on iOS

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, ios-app

How come the Stack Exchange app name does not fit?

[image: The name under the app icon is "Stack Exch..."]

I guess the title could be renamed "Exchange" or "Stack E" or some other creative name. I use the app quite often and I really like it, however it would be nice if the app name fit on the screen.

Comment: It fits very well on my iPhone 6 Plus. Perhaps it'd be helpful if you mentioned which iDevice you're using.

Comment: I am using the iPhone 6.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the font size you've selected in your settings than your device. I can't remember what it looked like on my iPhone 6 before uninstalling it, but I'm *pretty sure* it fit on the screen. I'm young, though, and use small text.

Comment: @CodyGray no, text scale doesn't seem to alter the app name sizing, I just tried it out on my 6S and see "Stack Exch..." at all scalings.

Comment: See [Use shorter home screen app title so that it doesn't get truncated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222335/use-shorter-home-screen-app-title-so-that-it-doesnt-get-truncated)

Comment: For me it was always like that in my iPhone, default settings. That's the one single thing the android app got better.

Comment: Same here on iPhone 6s, no special accessibility settings whatsoever (that I'm aware of)...

Comment: I use an iPhone 6 with the smallest font available. It doesn't fit.

Comment: I don't see the problem. "Stack Exch..." clearly identifies the app and clearly identifies that the full name doesn't fit underneath the icon. [tag:status-norepro].

Comment: I don't think the name should be changed. It's the the device settings/dimensions that shows the name as that - cropped. Even when renamed to `Stack E` or `Exchange` and some smaller dimension devices not able to show that completely will you rename that to `se`. Also, the app icons purpose is the same, to recognise the app just by seeing the icon and not the name.

Comment: @CodyGray It started to look like this after Apple introduced the new San Francisco font in iOS 9.

Comment: Unfortunate, but what other app with that logo that starts with "Stack Exch..." are you confusing it with?

Comment: Maybe if iphones weren't designed to fit in hipster's skinny jeans this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I think we should change the name of the website so it fits correctly on the iPhone.

Comment: I don't believe I should have to change my text size settings just to make one app name fit on my screen.

Comment: @MattBurland I was just mentioning that the app would look nicer if the title was displayed correctly.

Comment: How about Unicode 2261: **≣exchange** ?

Comment: @will iPhones haven't been designed to fit in hipster's skinny jeans for several iterations now. Have you *seen* the iPhone 6s Plus?

Comment: Using @peterept idea: file:///Users/pranavwadhwa/Desktop/Image.png

Comment: @ForceBru Good for you, not every one has a massive iDevice though.

Comment: @CodyGray That's the plus.  That's for normal human beings.  The tiny itsy bitsy form factor that was my favorite before you ever heard of it was and is still going strong.

Comment: I use this app for years — and I never noticed it.

Comment: @penatheboss You didn't do just that. [Screenshot for posterity](http://i.imgur.com/GHtpNdv.png).

Comment: would not keep it on apple level like iStack :D

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There fixed it

[image]

Comment: Well, these comments sure went south in a hurry. Let's not do that again.

Comment: Thanks for ruining our fun, @BradLarson.  Fun hater.

Comment: @Will - http://cdn.grumpycats.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/I-Had-Fun-Once-It-Was-Awful.jpeg

Comment: Will this be changed in the next update?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "iS exchange" to match the look and feel of iOS?

Comment: I dont think so that it is a good idea. I dont see Microsoft changing its display name to Micro or Soft if it doesn't fit an application view.

Everything has a brand value and market value.

Comment: Why is the e not capitalized?

Comment: @Trisped: Did you ever come across Experts Exchange?  What about capitalizing the C?

Comment: Ah, bummed I missed the original message chain

Comment: Let's hope the app store doesn't auto-correct the position of the space.

Comment: "Sex Change" can still be read
How about "Stack ⇆"?

Comment: @penatheboss Next update? That's a screenshot. Maybe it didn't roll out to you yet.

Comment: @nick Just so it stays registered, it had nothing to do with Brad Larson and Ms Yvette handled the situation so well I wish I could bake her some cookies. It was mostly me trolling some guy who was overly sensitive ("the internet is serious business"). I just wish sexuality was more like a pizza flavor. I don't see flame wars about anchovies ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @BradLarson I wanted to read the original comment chain you fun hater :(

Comment: @CamiloMartin Thanks for clarifying. You always have my permission to bake me cookies, by the way 

Comment: Hey @CamiloMartin will this be released in an update? I've had my hopes up for the past few ones, but I haven't seen any change.

Comment: @penatheboss Sorry, I was being sarcastic! As fun as it would be, no way they would roll this out. They probably just sat around asking themselves "Is Stack important?", "Is Exchange important?" until someone found a good excuse to leave it as it is ("That's the role of the ellipsis! To convey semantic *yada yada* mobile agile user experience cloud!"). Then whoever had a workable solution just thought it would be less boring to just agree with the course of inaction.

Comment: Ok. Clever idea though!

Answer (score -16):

Guys I came up with the perfect answer:

***StackXchange***

But that won't fit, so I chose

***Staxchange***

Comment: Still won't fit.  Try again.

Comment: Stop using spoiler markup. There's absolutely no reason for it here. And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114876/policy-for-spoilers-on-fiction-or-literature-sites/114923#114923

Comment: How about: Stage?

Comment: how about iClosed?

Comment: How about "Stack ⇆"?

Comment: Take it up a notch with "▤ ⇆" because, what's English when we can use symbol as universal language? :)